# В чем проблема. throw

Tags: php

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tests") or throw new Exception('Ошибка');
```

И ошибка: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'throw' (T_THROW) in H:\home\test\www\index.php on line 128

Answer (score 0):

Есть много причин, почему так делать нехорошо.

```
function my_query($query) {
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   if (!$result) {
       // тут можно ещё в лог кинуть всякой полезной инфы.
       throw new Exception('Ошибка');
   }
}
```

В целом, стоит отказаться от `mysql_*` и перейти на `mysqli_` или `PDO`.

Comment: Так почему ошибка-то выскакивает?

Comment: @Visman, Если коротко - несовместимость типов в операции. Если развёрнуто , то в ответе выше прекрасно всё написано

Comment: Если сделать так, то ошибка будет происходит непосредственно в функции, а не там где я эту функцию вызвал. Это разве хорошо?

Comment: @Erepaha, в исключение передавайте не `'Ошибка'`, а `'Ошибка в запросе '.$query` + http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @Erepaha, эта проблема легко решается пробросом исключения вверх по цепочке. А получаете вы гораздо больше. Теперь новая функция может быть независима от типа используемого драйвера для работы с БД. И вам не придётся переписывать весь код, а только эту функцию.

Comment: Как именно сделать этот подброс по цепочке? Что-то никак это до меня не дойдет.

Comment: Я вот понимаю что ловить исключения надо с помощью try и catch, но меня тревожит тот факт , что если я в каждом месте программы где нужно это исключение  буду его пихать, то код в таком случае будет очень громоздкий. Сколько уже статей почитал на эту тему и никак не могу понять самого главного))

Comment: То есть мне придется после каждого например запроса к базе делать блок кода try catch или как? обьясните мне это пожалуйста, а то я скоро голову с этим сломаю

Comment: Всё зависит от вашей архитектуры приложения. Обычно, если происходит исключение в работе БД, то смысла продолжать работу нет. Необходимо вывести ошибку. А исключения ловят и создают там же новое исключение с указанием старого. Так создаётся цепочка

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что конструкция `function() or other_function()` на самом деле является простой логической операцией, эксплуатирующей "ленивое" вычисление логических выражений.

`function() or other_function()` аналогично `function() || other_function()`

Суть в том, что второй операнд не вычисляется, если первый приведен к значению `TRUE`

Отсюда следует очень простой вывод - оба операнда(возвращаемые значения функций), в обязательном порядке, должны приводиться к булеву типу, что не выполняется в случае `throw new Exception`. Отсюда и ошибка.

PS И да, как вам правильно сказали - срочно уходите от расширения mysql, оно уже более 7 лет не развивается и в новых версиях PHP вообще отсутствует.

Comment: throw new Exception разве ничего не возвратит?

Comment: @Erepaha а что, по вашему, он может возвратить?

Comment: @Erepaha Это управляющая конструкция, как `if` или `for` например. Вам же не придет в голову написать что то типа `function() or if(a<b);`

Comment: вот теперь ясно, просто у меня всегда с этим throw возникало непонимание)